# why does enumeration(enum) falls into category of non composite data type

Tags: concepts

I can see that integer or pointer are non-composite data types whereas record and objects are composite data type. Similarly i guessed enumeration is composite because integers or string values can be used like in an array. Turns out it isn't.

Comment: An enumeration just represents a limited set of possible non-composite values a variable can take, but a variable can have only one value at a time (so, although the type itself is derived from another simple type, it's not a composite one, but more like a restriction on the original set of values - at least conceptually). It's not like an array.

Comment: What is your definition of "non-composite data type"? What is your definition of "enumeration"? Does your definition of "enumeration" comply with your definition of "non-composite data type"? If yes, then that is your answer: an enumeration is a non-composite data type because you defined a non-composite data type in such a way that it includes enumerations.

Comment: I can put objects in objects. I can put records in records. Not sure how I'd put an enum in an enum without doing some whacky encoding thing.

Comment: Technically, a pointer could be considered compound or composing of other types because a pointer is always a pointer *to another type*.

Answer (score 2):

Enums are generally implemented as integers, with names attached.  For example, Apple = 1, Banana = 2, Orange = 3, and so on.

As a result, they are really only scalar values, and not a composite anything.  Some languages allow enums to be converted back and forth to integers.  Others implement increment, decrement and comparison operators on them, so you can loop through the values.

Answer (score 0):

An enum can be "composed" of parts in the strictest sense, but a string enum is composed of characters and an integer is composed of bits.  You have to decide at what point the composition is meaningful.  You could have an enum Color.Tan; it could contain Red, Blue, Green values, or anything else for that matter.  However, enum implies that each component is constant and free of side effects, making the whole value constant.  Similar to thinking of a integer 5 as a single entity instead of a group of bits, you can also think of "tan" as a single entity without thinking of it's parts.